# UIDatePicker width is not going to set properly by using Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker, xcode12

I create date picker by using code. Date picker frame is set **properly** while application compile by using Xcode 11.6 but when application compile using Xcode 12.2 or above then Date picker **width causes problem** [Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2XAP.png).

```
        let screenWidth = self.view.frame.width
        let screenHeight = self.view.frame.height

        datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight - 216 - 44, width: screenWidth, height: 216))
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight - 216 - 44, width: screenWidth, height: 216)
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        }
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.minimumDate = getTwoWeekOldDateFormCurrentDate()
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        datePicker.setValue(UIColor.black, forKeyPath: "textColor")
        self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
```

I know, I am adding two time frame method in code, it will use for iOS 13.4 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in your viewController.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let screenWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let screenHeight = self.view.frame.height
    datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight - 216 - 44, width: screenWidth, height: 216)
}
```